# The use of blocks and modifiers properly

Tags: css, bem

I have a site where I've implemented the ABEM (an alternative to BEM, with an atomic design naming system), and now after a long coding spree, my brain is quite smush... I have a naming issue for a `<div>`

I've got a block that I've named: `.a-pipe` that has some text in it and some styling to it. This I then now style with a modifier to alter its colour due to the use of many different "pipe" variants. so i.e: `.--grey`, `.--blue`, `.--green`. And now with this and my confusion with using blocks, elements and modifiers I've come to a standstill with the issue of: should the `.a-pipe` be a block, and if so, should the variants of that block then have modifiers to change the colour and other stylings?

The HTML:

```
<div class="a-pipe --grey">some normal text <span class="a-pipe --lgText">Some larger text</span></div>

<div class="a-pipe --green">some normal text <span class="a-pipe --lgText">Some larger text</span></div>
```

The CSS:

```
.a-pipe {
 padding: 10px 3.5rem 10px 0;
 border-radius: 0px 10rem 10rem 0px / 0px 8.1rem 8.1rem 0px;
 text-align: right;
 color: white;
}

.a-pipe.--green {
 background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Your example uses `.a-pipe` twice, as a `div` and a `span` within it. Is that intentional? It seems to complicate the decision. But I'm not sure.

Comment: It is apart of my confusion xD... so thanks for pointing it out!